# Is there any way we can fail the task if it is running more than 10 hours in Airflow Dag

Tags: airflow

In Airflow scheduler, Task should forcefully fail if it is running more than 10 hours and at that point an alert should raised by the airflow process and terminating the job.

Is there any way we can achieve this. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define `execution_timeout`.
The default value of `execution_timeout` is tasks not having any timeout set.

You can override the value in specific operator by

```
    from datetime import timedelta
    op = MyOperator(
        ...
        execution_timeout=timedelta(VALUE),
    )
```

for example:

```
    op = BashOperator(
        task_id="my_task",
        execution_timeout=timedelta(days=2),
        bash_command="python my_script.py",
    )
```

Starting Airflow>=2.3.0 you can also set it globally with
[AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#default-task-execution-timeout)